# mongodb cronjobs with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to build something like this :

every morning 9:00 there will be some trigger to my node app where it pull randomly any document from the db and pass it to the view. What should I look into? Cronjob in node?

Sorry I'm new to mongodb

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule hope this will help,just google "Cronjob in node" for more options

Comment: @YanjunLin yea I know, just to verify what I'm going to search for is correct

Comment: practice will verify, and all roads lead to Rome

Comment: MongoDB is just the data base and be called whenever. Depending on how your program is laid out you could have an internal clock, have an external job or service like Jenkins kick things off too